# How to add swipe between navigation tabs in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

I got 3 navigation tabs with 3 different fragments in them.

How to add swipe between the fragments?

Comment: What are "navigation tabs"?

Comment: 3 tabs under the actionbar. When they are pressed they switch fragments

Comment: How did you implement "3 tabs under the action bar"?

Comment: with actionBar.newTab(), then TabListener initialised, with fragment

Comment: Note that action bar tabs are deprecated as of Android 5.0.

Comment: is it possible to add the swipe? or should I upgrade the code somehow? my sdk settings android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android made something for this exact reason called ViewPager!

in your onCreate method, do something like this:

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then,

Include the following into your MainActivity:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    private final String[] TITLES = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:  return OneFragment.newInstance(position);
            case 1:  return TwoFragment.newInstance(position);
            case 2:  return ThreeFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

The code I posted is code I use. It is more sophisticated than usual. It keeps track of the Fragments (each tab), allowing you to access Fragments from one another. So if you were in OneFragment, and wanted access to TwoFragment, you'd do something like:

*in OneFragment*

```
private void getTwoFragmentData() {
    data = (MainActivity) getActivity.getTwoFragmentData();
}
```

*in MainActivity*

```
public Data getTwoFragmentData() {
    TwoFragment twoFragment = (TwoFragment) adapter.getRegisteredFragment(1);
    return twoFragment.getData();    
}
```

Data above is just a placeholder for however you would interface with it, but the above code is the general structure of how you'd do it.

Also, you would edit the `getItem` method. And make the `switch, case` accordingly.

As an extra, you could do `pager.setOffScreenPageLimit(x)`, to also load the content `x` tabs away from your current tab, which is useful for retaining information. For 3 tabs, I would use `x = 2`, but ultimately, be wary because that is extra memory used.

Finally, the last little extra is that I use a library called `com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip` which is awesome for getting the bar underneath the tabs to swipe with you and make it look really clean. Adding it is very simple and you'll find more details [here](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

My `activity_main.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip -->
<!-- android:id="@+id/tabs" -->
<!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
<!-- android:layout_height="48dip" /> -->

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!-- android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" -->
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ignore the commented out stuff. That is what I use in addition to get the library I stated above integrated.

Comment: how does the pager xml looks like? my fragment displayer looks like this: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />